# my won't visual studio recognize the standard connection code: adapter.fill(myDataset)

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to setup a connection to a remote oracle db using OracleConnection in .NET 3.5 (I know it has been deprecated in later versions of .NET). Why won't Visual Studio recognize the statement myAdapter.fill(mydataset)

```
Imports System.Data.OracleClient //I compiled the project to .net 3.5. there is a warning for system.threading.tasks but not for system.data.oracleclient

Public Class Form1
Dim cString As String = "Data Source=usr/pw@host:1521/orcl"
Dim myCon As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(cString)
Dim myAdapter As OracleDataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter("select * from courses", cString)
Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
myAdapter.fill(myDataset) //Declaration expected
//this strange behavior might be a clue ... Dim m as OracleDataReader = new OracleDataReader yields overload resolution failed because no new is accessible
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `.Fill` in a function or subroutine.  You cannot use code in the form definition unless it's used to initialize a member.  I suspect you want something like:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim cString As String = "Data Source=usr/pw@host:1521/orcl"
Dim myCon As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(cString)
Dim myAdapter As OracleDataAdapter = New OracleDataAdapter("select * from courses", cString)
Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet

Private Sub FillData()
    myAdapter.fill(myDataset) 
End Sub
```

and then call `FillData` from wherever it's appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `fill()` (lower case *f*). However, there's [`Fill()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter.fill%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (upper case *F*).

Comment: 'Declaration expected' means… well, declaration expected. You cannot mix executable statements with declarations.